# Problems with SAGA on QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, saga

I'm trying to perform an interpolation on SAGA in QGIS but every time I ran the tool (or any other SAGA tool for that matter) I got the following message:

"The following layers were not correctly generated.

- C:/Users/Ronen/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_6af47249bd814d3e8868defb8ceab637/06a71a2ec1914aa69d2b5a600f18cdef/TABLE.shp
- C:/Users/Ronen/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_6af47249bd814d3e8868defb8ceab637/3d7ecad0e0fb468a8d6ba4fbdd06b380/SEGMENTS.sdat
- C:/Users/Ronen/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_6af47249bd814d3e8868defb8ceab637/94135e2aabc549f9b4b2885b81c51cc9/SIMILARITY.sdat

You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm."

When I check the Log Messages Panel, it displays the following error:

2019-01-03T17:01:35 WARNING warning:C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py:672: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

Does anyone know what that means?

Comment: Please could you look at the log message by clicking on the speech bubble in the bottom right hand of the screen and edit your question with the error?

Comment: 2019-01-03T17:01:35     WARNING    warning:C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py:672: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

Comment: It may be a problem with the way SAGA interprets the names of the layers in the `SHAPES` parameter. If you choose a _.shp_ file (with the three-point button called _Select file_ next to the drop-down menu) instead of a layer loaded to the project, as a point layer to interpolate, the problem persists?