# QGIS 3.22 incorrectly displaying raster layers

Tags: qgis, raster

Today, QGIS 3.22 incorrectly displays raster layers - by which I mean significantly in the wrong place and at the wrong scale. Moving the map with hand and zoom tool shows inconsistent updating (by which I mean, you select an area of the map with the zoom in tool and it loads a completely different area).
Checking a known area with the 'measure' and 'measure area' tool confirms these are not displaying correctly (e.g. a property that's around 48Ha measures as closer to 184Ha).
It does this with both new and previous project files. It also does this with both local raster files (downloaded from a government data service) AND the online WMS service.
Vector layers from previous project files (created and worked with over weeks perfectly fine without issue using 3.16) seem to appear correct - but the raster layers have the same issue.
Does anyone know what is going on?

[Note: when I reinstall v3.16 this issue appears to go away]
[image: montage of various representations of the same project data]

Comment: Could you please expand on "incorrectly displays". Did these rasters previously work in another version of QGIS. Were they working correctly yesterday and now Today are not? What does "inconsistent updating" mean? Please edit your question providing some additional info. Anything to help users answer your queries.

Comment: I have updated this above.

Comment: My first reaction was that the rasters lacked a coordinate system and 3.22 was  using a different coordinate system than your 3.16; and perhaps other settings for CRS and transformations were different.  But  if a fresh install of 3.16 works  I would assume the same settings.  You might check to be sure.  If you used the windows installer you might install 3.23 via the network installer in the OsGeo4W folder (you can have both), or if you have the latter try the windows installer, and see if the two versions operate differently for you.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS. I did check the CRS settings and tried several options (using a default / letting the layer determine it etc), but nothing worked. Just had to go back to 3.16 as it was just eating up too much time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Here is a link to discussion of the issue on github: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47158

Comment: ...so have they fixed it? It seemed inconclusive to me..