# Shapefile exported with CRS but CRS unknown when layer added to New Project

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, qgis-3

After right clicking and saving a defined CRS shapefile I open the layer in a new project, but the CRS is unknown. I thought that the Save Vector Layer as function permanently changes the CRS for the layer?

[image]Saved Shapefile referencing CRS

[image]Layer properties of saved shapefile showing unknown CRS

I'm using QGIS 3.22.

Comment: Is there a file with an extension ".prj" alongside the ".shp" file (and also a ".shx" and ".dbf")? That's where the projection is stored and if you don't copy every part of a shapefile then this can happen. Which is why I use GeoPackages now.

Comment: Yes the prj file shows 'unknown'. However I thought by defining the CRS when using the 'Save Vector Layer as' function the CRS is permanently changed?  I've tried saving as a geopackage and have the same issue.

Comment: I've gone back to the original shapefile that includes the correct CRS in the prj file. I tried to save specific features from this as both a shapefile and geopackage. Both files when added showed the CRS as 'unknown'. I then tried to use the Reproject process and this also produced a file with an unknown CRS.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it is unlikely we will be able to help you

Comment: What's the CRS of the layer *before* you start saving it? A quick test with a scratch layer in CRS:4326 *is* transformed to 3857 when using Save Vector Layer As... as a shapefile. But if your layer initially has an unknown CRS, how can QGIS figure out how to reproject it to your target CRS?

Comment: You need to do right-click on layer, Layer CRS... and set it to a known CRS so that Save As... can reproject if it needs to. If your layer has a question mark icon in the layer list then it has an unknown or missing CRS and saving won't work.

Comment: Yes I did the same with a scratch layer. The problem must be with the shp file I'm trying to save selected features from. The prj file has the correct crs, however when its loaded the crs is unknown. I've set the layer crs and then saved as both shp and geopackage files with the same unknown crs results and the prj file showing unknown.

Comment: I know what the issue is now as I had a similar issue downloading srtm dem files where the projection was also 'unknown'. Looking at this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/421861/96729 I used QGIS 3.18 and everthing was fine. There's a issue that's been raised but I can't find how to resolve in 3.22 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47158

Comment: Please create and use a new QGIS user profile and try if the issue does occur. If yes, please provide a sample layer or file an issue report in the QGIS GitHub repository with all the information required and attaching a sample layer and the detailed steps list to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled 3.22.11 previously loaded using osgeo4w and loaded 3.22.12 standalone. No projection issues then experienced.